# Rails 5: "belongs_to through" kind of association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

Happy New Year to everyone!

I have classic [has_many through association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association):

```
class Physician < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end
```

**However now I need to add `has_many` association from `class Appointment` to some `class Example`**, which is in `belongs_to` association with another model and would be in `belongs_to` association with `class Example`.

**If possible, how to to set this kind of assosiation?** Thank you.

**Update**

I don't understand, why this question is downvoted.
Here is what I need in `class Example` :

```
class Example < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :appointment
  belongs_to :model_bbb
end
```

**Update 2**

Ok, I figured out I can use solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116811/rails-belongs-to-through-association). Basically I can drop "Appointment" model and have `class Example` like this:

```
class Example < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
  belongs_to :model_bbb
end
```

Then in Physician and Patient I can do `has_many :examples` and another `through` relationship. I did wanted to do some strange `belongs_to through` thing as I could have relatively small table of `class Appointment`, but `class Example` table is expected to be quite big. So my initial thinking was not to create extra column which will be duplicated for so many times.

Comment: question is not understandable. so, what is problem with your last snippet? by the way, please edit tags to improve classfication - because this is a ruby-on-rails-5 thread.

Answer (score 2):

You could just add a has_many or has_many through to your Appointment model class.

Keep in mind that **belongs_to** association is *always* on the table that has the foreign key. So if you're right at your modeling you should have an appointment_id, for instance, on the examples table.

There's no problem using the associative table in relationship with another. Actually the idea of using an intermediate table is to be able to store other information on it (otherwhise you would be doing HABTM).

Comment: Thank you, please, check my Update 2 above. At the moment that seems the most effective solution to me. Please, comment if you have any other idea.